# Scrabble question about adding prefix and suffix in single play

Tags: scrabble

"Invest" is on the Scrabble board with spaces before and after. I have "d,e,e, and r" sitting in my tray. Is it legal to add "re" before and "ed" after in a single play, or is that double movement?

Answer (score 4):

Imagine the first play of a game was the word "cookie". The second play used the first o in cookie and played the letters m,n,s,t,e,r to score "monster"

That's basically the same thing you're asking.

That the letters in your question are prefixes and suffixes is irrelevant.

That you are adding to both sides of the word is irrelevant as evidenced by my first example.

I'll come back later with pictures.

It's a legal play.

Comment: While I don't disagree with this answer, it is worth noting that the [offical Scrabble rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules) regard "adding one or more letters to a word or letters already on the board" and "placing a word at right angles to a word already on the board" as _separate_ ways to form new words so I don't think it should be taken as a given that you can do this play because you can do the play in your example.

Comment: Full disclosure: I had little doubt as to the validity of my example. However, we occasionally play with a couple who seem to have a tenuous grasp of the rules.  For example, they insist that premium squares count for more than one play. I can picture them challenging my "reinvested" play. Therefore, I wanted some third-party backup in case the situation ever arises. As for the premium squares, my wife tells me: "Play along with them to avoid an argument. You and I will play a game the right way tomorrow night. "

Comment: @DouglasKellar Your wife is very wise.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Hard to think of a diplomatic way to tell longtime friends that they've been playing the game wrong for many years. Not with us. We've only played with them a couple of times.